# Find if binary number contains a set bit (or consecutive set bits) only using comparison operators

Tags: algorithm, mongodb, search, binary

I am not sure this is even possible, but I can't let it go for some reason.

I want to know if a store a number in a database how can I query for it based on if it has a certain bit set.

Example: The number I'm storing is 12 (1100) and I want to query the database and see if any number has the 2nd bit set (0100). I can't use bitwise operators here. Right now Im wondering if the only way to do this is querying for all possible permutations of binary numbers.

Is the only way to do this with querying for all possible permutations?

Comment: Don't store it as decimal but as binary number, which allows you to check for a certain digit being 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this (x / 2^b) % 2
where b is the bit number (zero based), / is an integer division, % is the mod operator and ^ is the power operator. Not sure how this would be expressed in MongoDB but it surely avoids using bitwise operators.

```
db.whatever.find( { $where: "this.somefield / 4 % 2 == 1" } )
```

For consecutive n consecutive bits starting at bit b, the expression to check would be:

```
(x / 2^b) % (2^n) == 2^n - 1
```

Comment: This may work, particular if you index off of the 2^b and then execute a $mod query, which seems to have better performance than $where. Since I am storing bit array as unsigned 32 bit integers, I can index off searching for numbers > the lowest bit in the consecutive bits...i.e if I am looking for 3 consecutive set bits starting at the 3rd bit, than that number has be greater than 2^3. I also can use the mod query on one of the x / 2^b fields.

Comment: I just provided the workaround the lack of bitwise operators. Your suggestion does indeed take care of performance issues by avoiding a full scan.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an efficient way to do this as MongoDB does not contain bitwise operators. It requires a full scan of every document. While you could use JavaScript to perform the `find` and the `$where` [operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), it will not be fast, especially for large collections, and I wouldn't recommend it, except for experiments:

```
var num = 2;   // checking 3rd bit 
var bit = (Math.pow(2, num)).toString();
var query = "(this.bitValue & " + bit + ") > 0";
db.testCollection.find( { $where: query } )
```

You can further optimize it possibly by doing a filter on the number:

```
db.testCollection.find({ bitValue: { $gte : bit }, $where: query } )
```

You could then index `bitValue` and find only numbers greater than or equal to the bit you're checking. That would prevent a full table scan.